# Minimize difference between indicator variables in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm new to Matlab and want to write a program that chooses the value of a parameter (P) to minimize the difference between two vectors, where each vector is a variable in a dataframe. The first vector (call it A) is a predetermined vector of 1s and 0s, and the second vector (call it B) has each of its entries determined as an indicator function that depends on the value of the parameter P and other variables in the dataframe. For instance, let C be a third variable in the dataset, so

A = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]

B = [x, y, z, u, v]

where x = 1 if (C[1]+10)^0.5 - P > (C[1])^0.5 and otherwise x = 0, and similarly, y = 1 if (C[2]+10)^0.5 - P > (C[2])^0.5 and otherwise y = 0, and so on.

I'm not really sure where to start with the code, except that it might be useful to use the fminsearch command. Any suggestions?

Edit:  I changed the above by raising to a power, which is closer to the actual example that I have. I'm also providing a complete example in response to a comment:
Let A be as above, and let C = [10, 1, 100, 1000, 1]. Then my goal with the Matlab code would be to choose a value of P to minimize the differences between the coordinates of the vectors A and B, where B[1] = 1 if (10+10)^0.5 - P > (10)^0.5 and otherwise B[1] = 0, and similarly B[2] = 1 if (1+10)^0.5 - P > (1)^0.5 and otherwise B[2] = 0, etc. So I want to choose P to maximize the likelihood that A[1] = B[1], A[2] = B[2], etc.

I have the following setup in Matlab, where ds is the name of my dataset:

```
ds.B = zeros(size(ds,1),1);     % empty vector to fill
for i = 1:size(ds,1)
if ((ds.C(i) + 10)^(0.5) - P > (ds.C(i))^(0.5))
    ds.B(i) = 1;
else 
    ds.B(i) = 0;
end
end
```

Now I want to choose the value of P to minimize the difference between A and B. How can I do this?

EDIT: I'm also wondering how to do this when the inequality is something like (C[i]+10)^0.5 - P*D[i] > (C[i])^0.5, where D is another variable in my dataset. Now P is a scalar being multiplied rather than just added. This seems more complicated since I can't solve for P exactly. How can I solve the problem in this case?

Comment: So, if ```P<10 -> x = 1```, otherwise ```x = 0```, irrespective of the value of ```C[1]```, is that correct? Could you please provide a complete example of the result you would expect, writing in full the values of A, C and P, as well as the resulting value of B?

Comment: I noticed you posted a related question after this one? It was noodling around in my brain for a while, and I just figured out the answer. But it looks like the question is gone? If you want to repost it, I can give an answer in a couple of days.

Comment: Thanks. I've reposted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75194207/matlab-code-to-minimize-multivariate-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT 1:  It seems `fminbnd()` isn't optimal, likely due to the stairstep nature of the indicator function.  I've updated to test the midpoints of all the regions between indicator function flips, plus endpoints.

EDIT 2:  Updated to include dataset D as a coefficient of P.

---

If you can package your distance calculation up in a single function based on P, you can then search for its minimum.

```
arraySize = 1000;
ds.A = double(rand([arraySize,1]) > 0.5);
ds.C = rand(size(ds.A));
ds.D = rand(size(ds.A));
B = @(P)double((ds.C+10).^0.5 - P.*ds.D > ds.C.^0.5);

costFcn = @(P)sqrt(sum((ds.A-B(P)).^2));

% Solving the equation (C+10)^0.5 - P*D = C^0.5 for P, and sorting the results
BCrossingPoints = sort(((ds.C+10).^0.5-ds.C.^0.5)./ds.D);
% Taking the average of each crossing point with its neighbors
BMidpoints = (BCrossingPoints(1:end-1)+BCrossingPoints(2:end))/2;
% Appending endpoints onto the midpoints
PsToTest = [BCrossingPoints(1)-0.1; BMidpoints; BCrossingPoints(end)+0.1];
% Calculate the distance from A to B at each P to test
costResult = arrayfun(costFcn,PsToTest);
% Find the minimum cost
[~,lowestCostIndex] = min(costResult);
% Find the optimum P
optimumP = PsToTest(lowestCostIndex);

ds.B = B(optimumP);

semilogx(PsToTest,costResult)
xlabel('P')
ylabel('Distance from A to B')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answer. I have one follow-up question. It seems that, even when I change the function a bit, e.g. changing the power or the constant (10) being added, I always end up with a vector ds.B that is either all 0's or all 1's. Is this a result of the way the code is structured, or is this the nature of the particular function I've chosen? Ideally I would like to allow the option that the elements of B can differ.

Comment: It's likely a result of the inputs and indicator function.  I was able to get B = [0 0 0 1 0] with C = [50 0 100 500 3] and function C+10-P>C.^0.5

Comment: Well, it looks like fminbnd may not be right for your application, likely due to the stairstep nature of the distance function.  I changed my answer to use a different technique of finding the minimum distance.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. When I apply this to my data, I'm getting the following error associated with the line `PsToTest = [BCrossingPoints(1)-0.1, BMidpoints, BCrossingPoints(end)+0.1];`

`Error using horzcat
Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent.` Could you please explain how BCrossingPoints and BMidpoints are being defined? I'm not yet following the intuition.

Comment: @RK124 Looking at your example above, it appears that you are using column vectors, while my example was using row vectors.  I edited my answer to match yours, which meant replacing commas in the arrays with semicolons.  It should work now on your data.  I also added comments to the answer to explain what each step is for.

Comment: Thanks again for your help with this. I'm wondering whether I can use a similar method to solve for a value that gets multiplied by a vector (i.e. one of the other variables). For instance, if the equation is B = @(P)double((ds.C+10).^0.5 - P*ds.D > ds.C.^0.5), where ds.D is another variable in the dataset. When I try to divide the entire thing by ds.D to define BCrossingPoints (i.e. solving for P), I get the error `Requested 37885x37885 (21.4GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference (8.0GB)`. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: That should work fine. What are the variable sizes just before the step that’s erroring? It sounds like one of your data sets is a row vector and one is a column vector, so when you try to perform element-wise operations, they get implicitly expanded into a square. For more info, try [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/compatible-array-sizes-for-basic-operations.html)

Comment: After thinking about this a bit more, I'm not sure I understand conceptually how to adapt the above to the case where B = @(P)double((ds.C+10).^0.5 - P*ds.D > ds.C.^0.5). Since "dividing a vector by another vector" isn't really mathematically defined, I don't really understand how to define BCrossingPoints in this case...I will edit my original question to inquire about this in a bit more depth.

Comment: I gather you want each element of B to depend only on its corresponding partners in C and D? You’ll want to use element-wise division, rather than matrix division. I’ll edit my answer above to accommodate. You can learn more [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html).

Answer (score -1):

**1.-** `x` is assumed positive real only, because with `x<0` then complex values show up.

Since no comment is made in the question it seems reasonable to assume `x real` and `x>0` only.

As requested, **P** 'the parameter' a scalar, **P** only has 2 significant states `>0` or `<0`, let's see how is this:

**2.-** The following lines generate kind-of random A and C.

Then a sweep of p is carried out and distances d1 and d2 are calculated.

`d1` is euclidean distance and `d2` is the absolute of the difference between **A** and and **B** converting both from binary to decimal:

```
N=10
% A=[1 0 0 1 0]
A=randi([0 1],1,N);
% C=[10 1 1e2 1e3 1]
C=randi([0 1e3],1,N)

p=[-1e4:1:1e4];  % parameter to optimize

B=zeros(1,numel(A));

d1=zeros(1,numel(p));  % euclidean distance
d2=zeros(1,numel(p));  % difference distance

for k1=1:1:numel(p)
    B=(C+10).^.5-p(k1)>C.^.5;
        d1(k1)=(sum((B-A).^2))^.5;
    d2(k1)=abs(sum(A.*2.^[numel(A)-1:-1:0])-sum(B.*2.^[numel(A)-1:-1:0]));
end

figure;
plot(p,d1)
grid on
xlabel('p');title('d1')
```

[image]

```
figure
plot(p,d2)
grid on
xlabel('p');title('d2')
```

[image]

The only degree of freedom to optimise seems to be the sign of **P** regardless of **|P|** value.

**3.-** f(p,x) has either no root, or just one root, depending upon `p`

The threshold funtion is

```
if f(x)>0 then B(k)==1 else B(k)==0
```

this is

```
f(p,x)=(x+10)^.5-p-x^.5
```

Now

`(x+10).^.5-p>x.^.5` is same as `(x+10).^.5-x.^.5>p`

There's a range of `p` that keeps `f(p,x)=0` without any (real) root.

For the particular case `p=0` then `(x+10).^.5` and `x.^.5` do not intersect (until `Inf` reached = there's no intersection)

```
figure;plot(x,(x+10).^.5,x,x.^.5);grid on
[![enter image description here][3]][3]
    
y2=diff((x+10).^.5-x.^.5)
figure;plot(x(2:end),y2);
grid on;xlabel('x')
title('y2=diff((x+10).^.5-x.^.5)')
[![enter image description here][3]][3]
% 005
```

This means the condition `f(x)>0` is always true holding all bits of **B=1**. With B=1 then `d(A,B)` turns into `d(A,1)`, a constant.

However, for a certain value of `p` then there's one root and `f(x)>0` is always false keeping all bits of **B=0**.

In this case `d(A,B)` the cost function turns into `d(A,0)` and this is **A** itself.

**4.- P as a vector**

The optimization gains in degrees of freedom if instead of **P** scalar, **P** is considered as vector.

For a given `x` there's a value of `p` that switches **B(k)** from 0 to 1.

Any value of `p` below such threshold keeps **B(k)=0**.

Equivalently, inverting `f(x)` :

```
g(p)=(10-p^2)^2/(4*p^2)>x
```

Values of `x` below this threshold bring **B** closer to **A** because for each element of **B** it's flipped to the element value of **A**.

Therefore, it's convenient to consider P as a vector, not a ascalar, and :

For all, or as many (as possible) elements of **C** to meet `c(k)<(10-p^2)^2/(4*p^2)` in order to get **C=A** or
minimize **d(A,C)**

**5.- roots of f(p,x)**

```
syms t positive
p=[-1000:.1:1000];
zp=NaN*ones(1,numel(p));
sol=zeros(1,numel(p));
for k1=1:1:numel(p)
  p(k1)
    eq1=(t+10)^.5-p(k1)-t^.5-p(k1)==0;
    s1=solve(eq1,t);
    if ~isempty(s1) 
        zp(k1)=s1;
    end
end

nzp=~isnan(zp);
zp(nzp)
```

returns

```
 =
  
  620.0100  151.2900   64.5344   34.2225   20.2500   12.7211
 
    8.2451    5.4056    3.5260    2.2500    1.3753    0.7803
 
    0.3882    0.1488    0.0278
```

Comment: Your point #2 suffers from lack of sampling resolution.  If you change to `p=[0:.01:2];`, you'll see interesting behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand point #3 fully. With p==0, I do see that B will always be false.  However with positive P, the presence of a root means that for small values of C the function's result will be left of that root and therefore true, while for large values of C the function's result will be right of that root and therefore false.  Then given an array of independent values of C, you will get an array of independent values of B.

Comment: The suggested reduction of the step, to increase resolution, is for the question originator to decide. Sometimes there may be need for improvements to a given answer, but the solution points on the right direction. Why don't we leave it to the question originator, if interested, to add further coment?

Comment: On the contrary, the fact that there’s a domain of P where the cost function returns distances different from the extremes makes your conclusion in point 2 simply wrong. It doesn’t really matter if it’s me or the OP that notices it. In addition, it actually leads in the wrong direction, suggesting that one can just choose a positive or negative P and be done, when the actual minimum (which the OP was looking for) is usually in that small middle region.